# How to to code on browse button & run button

Tags: vba, excel, userform

[image]

How can I link the code for the run button with the file browse via the browse button?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get to the code of a userform:

## 1 double-click on button you want the code to be run with

## 2 right-click on userform and select "Show Code"

**Extra Tip:**

Put the code you want to run in a seperate module and do this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call modulename.subname ' this is your code
End Sub
```

In this way you will be able to reuse your code.

**Another Tip [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: Hi, I need a code for the browse button to select the file and then when i click the start button it will get the file from the browse button to run the macro.